# Python 2.7.9 troubles importing pysftp

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-module, pysftp

I've been having troubles import pysftp. I currently have a server running some python scripts on a database, and decided to try and update this module which some of the scripts use. It broke a bunch of the scripts and then I had to go back and fix the versioning and to allow everything to function.

So far the only module I'm not able to import or use is pysftp. It throws the attached error. I've tried going into sites-manager and removing the files from there, however it has yet to help. Everything else has been working. Updating doesn't work either.

Any indication on how to resolve this error is greatly appreciated.

Error is:

```
ImportError: cannot import name util
```

I haven't been able to find a package called util to install. Please help! Attached link is of the trace.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGz82.jpg

Comment: Please post the error here instead of providing a link. Also, which version of pysftp are you using?

Comment: The error was posted above, 3rd line from the bottom. 

ImportError: cannot import name util 

also I'm using pysftp 0.2.9